# hp-ux preserve owner of file with cpio

Tags: unix

i want to preserve file ownership when copying file with cpio on hp-ux

can you help me

i am running this command with non root user

Answer (score 0):

it's only possible with root user and with -U option

Comment: I have checked manual for GNU cpio and there is no -U option.